# D3.. trying to add labels to a bar chart, adds all values to each label

Tags: d3.js, label

I'm relatively new to D3 and trying to add labels to a bar chart.. I keep running into the problem of labels applying all values to each label.  Precedding this code is normal data load etc.

```
        // Controls Bar Layout and Offset (x(d.weekOf)+20)

    var property = svg.selectAll(".property")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "g")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + (x(d.weekOf)+20) + ",0)"; });

    //  Theese are the bars, width is the width of the bars

    property.selectAll("rect")
        .data(function(d) { return d.emissions; })
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("width", "80")
        .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
        .attr("opacity", "0.7")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

    //  Add Capacity Labels

    property.selectAll("text")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        .text(function(d, i) {return d.Internal; })
        .attr("x", 41)
        .attr("y", 210)
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
```

Clearly I'm missing something simple..?

Comment: It's not the cause of the problem you're asking about but another potential issue is that you're selecting '.property' but setting the class to 'g'. If you refresh the data and run through this code again it will create new nodes every time. You should probably be selecting for '.g' so you pick up existing nodes for rebinding.

Answer (score 1):

Your labels are a subselection of the property selection, so instead of using data() to join each property label to the entire dataset as you are, you should instead use data to join to the corresponding parent datum, like so:

```
 property.selectAll("text")
    .data(function(d) {return [d];})
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d, i) {return d.Internal; })
    .attr("x", 41)
    .attr("y", 210)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle");
```